# Find out if the socket was accepted or not

Tags: c++, sockets

I have basic example of using `poll()` method:

```
struct pollfds fds[5];
int nfds = 1;

fds[0].fd = listen_sd;
fds[0].events = POLLIN;

while(1) {
    int ret = poll(fds, nfds, 0);

    if (ret < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    int size = nfds;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (fds[i].revents == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (fds[i].revents != POLLIN) {
            exit(1);
        }

        if (fds[i].fd == listen_sd) {
            // Something happened on the server
            // If there is a client which wasn't accepted yet, it returns its fd
            int new = accept(listen_sd, null, null);
            // If there is a client which was already accepted,
            // it doesn't return anything, just loop in accept() method

        } else {
            // Something happened on a different socket than the server
        }
    }
}
```

All messages from clients will flow through server socket.

It means there is always something happened on the server socket, isn't it?

But how can I do something like this (in true condition):

- Try to accept a socket, some function should return: the socket is already
  accepted, the socket hasn't been accepted yet.
- When the socket is already accepted - receive the data.
- When the socket hasn't been accepted yet - accept the socket and
  receive the data.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, a TCP socket listening for connections will enter a readable state when it has a client connection waiting to be accepted.  Call `accept()` to actually accept the connection, and then you can start monitoring for read/write/close states on the new TCP socket returned by `accept()`.  This is a completely separate socket than the one that is listening for connections.  Add it to your `pollfds` array so you can poll both it and the listening socket at the same time.

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<pollfds> fds;

{
pollfds listen_pf;
listen_pf.fd = listen_sd;
listen_pf.events = POLLIN;
listen_pf.push_back(listen_pf);
}

while (true) {
    int ret = poll(fds.data(), fds.size(), 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t i = 0, size = fds.size();

    while (i < size) {
        if (fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
            if (fds[i].fd == listen_sd) {
                // accept a pending client connection...
                int client_sd = accept(listen_sd, NULL, NULL);
                if (client_sd != -1) {
                    pollfds client_pf;
                    client_pf.fd = client_sd;
                    client_pf.events = POLLIN | POLLOUT | POLLRDHUP;
                    fds.push_back(client_pf);
                }
            }
            else {
                // read data from fds[i].fd as needed...
                if (read fails) {
                    fds.erase(fds.begin()+i);
                    --size;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fds[i].revents & POLLOUT) {
            // write pending data to fds[i].fd as needed ...
            if (write fails) {
                fds.erase(fds.begin()+i);
                --size;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (fds[i].revents & (POLLERR | POLLHUP | POLLNVAL)) {
            if (fds[i].fd == listen_fd) {
                exit(1);
            }
            else {
                fds.erase(fds.begin()+i);
                --size;
                continue;
            }
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
```

On the client side, a TCP socket connecting to a server will enter a writable state when `connect()` is successful and the connection has been fully established with the server and is ready for I/O.